# Does two pronged attack stack with Row enhance?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

If I connect 4 orbs, and I connect a row as well, would the two pronged attack activate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since 5+ connected orbs do a mass attack. But, if you were to connect 4 orbs then 4 more it would work. The lines of orbs can't be touching of course.

Answer (score 1):

**It depends on what you mean by "activate".**

The two-prong awakening has 2 effects when triggered. First, it replaces the card's normal 1-target attack with a 2-target attack. Second, it multiples the damage *for that match* by 1.5 (for that card only).

There are essentially 3 attack modes: the normal 1-target attack, the 2-target attack from the two prong awakening, and the mass attack from a match of 5+ orbs. Cards will always use the best attack mode that was triggered for their color, so if you get a TPA match of 4 orbs and a mass attack match of 5+ orbs (such as a row), then cards of that color will make a mass attack, because attacking all enemies is better than attacking only two of them.

The two prong damage bonus, on the other hand, is definitely *not* overridden. This is difficult to test, but you can do so by getting two of the same card, getting them both to the same level (so they have the same attack) and awakening the TPA awakening for only one of them. Then bring both to a dungeon and match a TPA and a 5+ orb match; you'll see the card that has the TPA awakening will do more damage.

**TLDR:** A mass attack will replace the split attack from TPAs, but you'll still get the TPA damage bonus.